# PHPUnit - does nothing, no errors, no output

Tags: phpunit

Sorry for another 'phpunit doesn't work' question. It used to work for years now. Today I reinstalled PEAR and phpunit for reasons not connected to this problem. Now when I run phpunit as I usually did. Nothing happens. The cli just shows me a new line, no output whatsoever.

Has anyone encountered this problem or has an idea what could have caused it.

```
PHPUnit Version: 3.5.15 
PEAR Version: 1.9.4 
PHP Version: 5.3.8 
Windows 7
```

Comment: Create the simplest test class you can without a `bootstrap.php` or `phpunit.xml` to first verify that your new installation works. PHPUnit will stop without any message if it cannot instantiate all of the test cases--one for each test method and data provider.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Thanks to your suggestion I was able to solve the problem. After a couple of random changes, phpunit started outputting regular error messages. If you'd post this comment as an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Create the simplest test class you can without a `bootstrap.php` or `phpunit.xml` to first verify that your new installation works. PHPUnit will stop without any message if it cannot instantiate all of the test cases--one for each test method and data provider--before running any tests.

Comment: This answer helped me as well. The problem in my case was setting up a proper route and removing an accesscontrol check in the controller in case the ENVIRONMENT was testing.

Answer (score 57):

I'm on OSX and MAMP. To get error messages I had to adjust the following entries in `php.ini`:

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```

Please not that this has to go into `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini` .

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to modify the CLI version of php.ini, which may be different. Quick shortcut to locate it: `php -i | grep php.ini`

Comment: This solution changes the php.ini for all the apps those using the same php binary, which makes it too broad to be correct :)
I would recommend to specify the unit-test related config (ini) in the `phpumit.xml` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458644/phpunit-does-nothing-no-errors-no-output/28714448#28714448)

Answer (score 56):

For future reference, for those who are facing any problem with PHPUnit, and PHPUnit is failing silently, just add this three lines inside phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit ....... >
    ...
    ...
    <php>
         <ini name="display_errors" value="true"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

After that run the tests again, and now you can see why PHPUnit is failing,

AND ... ENJOY UNIT TESTING :)

Comment: Adding the following to the `<php>` element may also help: `<ini name="error_log" value="./test_error.log"/>`

Answer (score 31):

One more thing that can cause PHPUnit to fail silently (i.e. it just stops running tests without telling you why) is that it has an error handler that it set up before each test run, which is intended to capture errors and display them at the end of the test run. The problem is that certain errors halt execution of the whole test run.

What I generally do when this happens, as a first step, is reset the error handler to something that will immediately output the error message. In my base test class I have a method called `setVerboseErrorHandler`, which I'll call at the top of the test (or in `setUp`) when this happens. The below requires php 5.3 or higher (due to the closure), so if you're on 5.2 or lower you can make it a regular function.

```php
protected function setVerboseErrorHandler() 
{
    $handler = function($errorNumber, $errorString, $errorFile, $errorLine) {
        echo "
ERROR INFO
Message: $errorString
File: $errorFile
Line: $errorLine
";
    };
    set_error_handler($handler);        
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You have already figured out how to get it to work, but my solution was a little different.

First thing you can do is check the exit status.  If it's not 0, then PHP exited and because of the INI configuration settings set, none of the PHP error messages were outputted.  What I did was to enable the "display_errors" INI setting, and set "error_reporting" to `E_ALL`.  I was then able to identify errors such as PHP not being able to parse a certain script.  Once I fixed that, PHPUnit ran properly.

Comment: For people new to bash, check the exit status with `echo $?` (which gives you the status code of the last command, 0 means OK).

Comment: This is actually the best answer to my opinion, because when exit code is 255 then setting error_reporting won't help much.

Comment: so why is the best? I got 255 and have no clue what to do :)
@eddy147

Answer (score 7):

I managed to spectacularly paint myself in a corner with a custom "fatal error handler" that in certain rare conditions turned out to output *nothing*. Those conditions, in accordance with Murphy's Law, materialized once I had forgotten the handler was in place.

Since it wasn't really a "PHPunit problem", none of the other answers helped [although @David's problem was at the bottom the same thing], even though the symptoms were the same - phpunit terminating with no output, no errors, no log and no clue.

In the end I had to resort to a step-by-step tracing of the whole test suite by adding this in the bootstrap code:

```
register_shutdown_function(function() {
    foreach ($GLOBALS['lastStack'] as $i => $frame) {
        print "{$i}. {$frame['file']} +{$frame['line']} in function {$frame['function']}\n";
    }
});
register_tick_function(function() {
    $GLOBALS['lastStack'] = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 8);
});
declare(ticks=1);
```

If anyone ever manages to do worse than this, and somehow block stdout as well, this modification should work:

```
register_shutdown_function(function() {
    $fp = fopen("/tmp/path-to-debugfile.txt", "w");
    foreach ($GLOBALS['lastStack'] as $i => $frame) {
        fwrite($fp, "{$i}. {$frame['file']} +{$frame['line']} in function {$frame['function']}\n");
    }
    fclose($fp);
});
```

Comment: Great answer ! Helped me found some `@unserialize` call failing about `memory_limit` problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

an old thread this one, but one I stumbled across when having the same problem.

I had the same problem, nothing being returned to console including print, print_r, echo etc.

solved it by using `--stderr` as a [test-runner](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html) option.

Answer (score 4):

Check that you haven't written any logic into your code that just dies, with no output. For example,

```
<?php

if (!array_key_exists('SERVER_NAME', $_SERVER)) {
    die();
}
```

This was exactly my case; I'd made some assumptions about the environment which were correct when running the code via Apache, but weren't fulfilled when running from CLI and the code did not echo any output.

PHPUnit tried to include the bootstrap file before giving the usual init output, but died during the bootstrapping proccess, hence exiting with status 0 and no output.

Comment: Cheer up. I made some assumptions on the blessed *database*.

Answer (score 4):

If when you run from command line a recent version of phpunit like this

```
> php phpunit
or
> ./phpunit
or
> php ./phpunit.phar
or
> ./phpunit.phar
```

And you immediatly return to the prompt with no messages, this is probably due to a "suhosin secutiry" setup.
phpunit is now a "phar" package including all libraries. To be able to run such file when php has the suhosin security module enabled, you must first set this

```
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar
```

into you php.ini file (for example, with debian/ubuntu, you may have to edit file /etc/php5/conf.d/suhosin.ini

Comment: I recommend also reading the Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suhosin

Answer (score 3):

i tried everything here, but nothing worked until i tried `phpunit --no-configuration simpletest.php`. that finally gave me some output, which implies that my `phpunit.xml.dist` file is broken. (i'll come back and update this once i debug it.)

the contents of `simpletest.php` are below, but any test file should work.

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class FooTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testFoo()
    {
        $this->assertEquals('x', 'y');
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem; I had no output when running my test. Fortunately, by running your `simpletest.php` phpunit showed output. It was a major step in setting up my first test. The cause for no output in my situation was caused by the include path; the path to autoloader was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the phpunit you're running and the one you installed are the same:

```
$ pear list phpunit/phpunit
...
script /path/to/phpunit
...
```

Try to execute exactly that phpunit with the full path.

Then check your PATH variable and see if the correct directory is in it. If not, fix that.

---

If that does not help, use write something into the phpunit executable, e.g. "echo 123;" and run phpunit. Check if you see that.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but everything is all right with my install, I have only the one version I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

For me the conflict was with Xdebug's directive

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using composer, **check to make sure your included PHP files are not ending the code executions**. The same goes for when you included certain PHP files explicitly.

In my case, I was working on a WordPress plugin and one of the PHP files I included directly in composer.json (which I don't want to load through PSR-4 because WordPress's coding standards don't support it yet) had this code on top;

```
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit(); // exit if accessed directly
}
```

And since `ABSPATH` will not be defined when I run the tests directly, the code was exiting.
This is because, since I told Composer to always load these files each time, this part of the code will execute, while the other files included though autoload PSR will load on demand.

**So check to make sure any of the files you included are not stopping the code execution**. If it happens, then even when you run `phpunit --info` the code will still exit and you won't see any output.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a seems problem. I could run phpunit from root directory but not from anywhere else. so I put the "--configuration" tag, and point it to my xml configuration.

```sh
$ ./<path_to_phpunit>phpunit --configuration <path_to_phpunitxml>/phpunit.xml
```

The path to phpunit is optinal, I used it because I installed locally by composer.

Answer (score 0):

In `/composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php` in `main()` function in `catch (Throwable $t) {}` block `var_dump` (echo / print_r) exception. If an exception exists, you, probably, will solve the current problem.