# php vendor/bin/phpunit empty result Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

I try to start my test with command

> php vendor/bin/phpunit

but nothing happens

http://joxi.ru/Vm66DpgFDO7nvm

but if i try to execute command

```
php vendor/bin/phpunit --filter Test2484 tests/Unit/Test2484.php
```

i have result

http://joxi.ru/zANdqxKFBQKqam

what could be the problem?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458644/phpunit-does-nothing-no-errors-no-output) might help

Comment: Please try: `php -f vendor/bin/phpunit -- --verbose --debug` - this will show you the configuraiton file and list each test on it's own.